TNT explosion after death
How to use the bedrock command in Minecraft so that every time you die you blow up, so that you can, for example, fly on someone's elites and play in the game as a kamikaze

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi, welcome to Arcade. You probably don’t know us, but this site (and most others on the Stack Exchange network) are English only. If you are able to translate this yourself, feel free to do so.

How to use the bedrock command in Minecraft so that every time you die you blow up, so that you can, for example, fly on someone's elites and play in the game as a kamikaze
